# rosmake rgbdslam_freiburg error in groovy

Tags: ros, rgbdslam-freiburg, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is my terminal information:

```
> mkdir -p bin
cd build && cmake -Wdev -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/opt/ros/groovy/share/ros/core/rosbuild/rostoolchain.cmake  ..
[rosbuild] Building package rgbdslam
-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /home/turtlebot/rgbdslam_freiburg/rgbdslam/build/devel
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /opt/ros/groovy
-- This workspace overlays: /opt/ros/groovy
-- Using Debian Python package layout
-- Using CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING: ON
-- Skip enable_testing() for dry packages
-- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /home/turtlebot/rgbdslam_freiburg/rgbdslam/build/test_results
-- Found gtest sources under '/usr/src/gtest': gtests will be built
-- catkin 0.5.71
[rosbuild] Including /opt/ros/groovy/share/roslisp/rosbuild/roslisp.cmake
[rosbuild] Including /opt/ros/groovy/share/roscpp/rosbuild/roscpp.cmake
[rosbuild] Including /opt/ros/groovy/share/rospy/rosbuild/rospy.cmake
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:96 (find_package):
  Could not find module Findlibg2o.cmake or a configuration file for package
  libg2o.

  Adjust CMAKE_MODULE_PATH to find Findlibg2o.cmake or set libg2o_DIR to the
  directory containing a CMake configuration file for libg2o.  The file will
  have one of the following names:

    libg2oConfig.cmake
    libg2o-config.cmake




------------------------------------------------------------------

Compiling SiftGPU...
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/turtlebot/rgbdslam_freiburg/rgbdslam/external/siftgpu/linux'
mkdir -p ../../../build/siftgpu
mkdir -p ./bin 
ln ../data/ -d -s -f
ar rcs ./bin/libsiftgpu.a ../../../build/siftgpu/FrameBufferObject.o ../../../build/siftgpu/GlobalUtil.o ../../../build/siftgpu/GLTexImage.o ../../../build/siftgpu/ProgramGLSL.o ../../../build/siftgpu/ProgramGPU.o ../../../build/siftgpu/ShaderMan.o ../../../build/siftgpu/SiftGPU.o ../../../build/siftgpu/SiftPyramid.o ../../../build/siftgpu/PyramidGL.o ../../../build/siftgpu/SiftMatch.o
g++ -o ./bin/libsiftgpu.so ../../../build/siftgpu/FrameBufferObject.o ../../../build/siftgpu/GlobalUtil.o ../../../build/siftgpu/GLTexImage.o ../../../build/siftgpu/ProgramGLSL.o ../../../build/siftgpu/ProgramGPU.o ../../../build/siftgpu/ShaderMan.o ../../../build/siftgpu/SiftGPU.o ../../../build/siftgpu/SiftPyramid.o ../../../build/siftgpu/PyramidGL.o ../../../build/siftgpu/SiftMatch.o -lGLEW -lglut -lIL -lGL -lX11 -g -O2 -I../include -fPIC -L/usr/lib64 -L/usr/lib -L./bin -Wall -Wno-deprecated -pthread   -march=native -mfpmath=sse -shared -fPIC
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/turtlebot/rgbdslam_freiburg/rgbdslam/external/siftgpu/linux'

------------------------------------------------------------------

-- Eigen found (include: /usr/include/eigen3)
[rosbuild] Couldn't find source file /home/turtlebot/rgbdslam_freiburg/rgbdslam/build/src/moc_qtros.cxx; assuming that it is in /home/turtlebot/rgbdslam_freiburg/rgbdslam and will be generated later
[rosbuild] Couldn't find source file /home/turtlebot/rgbdslam_freiburg/rgbdslam/build/src/moc_openni_listener.cxx; assuming that it is in /home/turtlebot/rgbdslam_freiburg/rgbdslam and will be generated later
[rosbuild] Couldn't find source file /home/turtlebot/rgbdslam_freiburg/rgbdslam/build/src/moc_qt_gui.cxx; assuming that it is in /home/turtlebot/rgbdslam_freiburg/rgbdslam and will be generated later
[rosbuild] Couldn't find source file /home/turtlebot/rgbdslam_freiburg/rgbdslam/build/src/moc_graph_manager.cxx; assuming that it is in /home/turtlebot/rgbdslam_freiburg/rgbdslam and will be generated later
[rosbuild] Couldn't find source file /home/turtlebot/rgbdslam_freiburg/rgbdslam/build/src/moc_glviewer.cxx; assuming that it is in /home/turtlebot/rgbdslam_freiburg/rgbdslam and will be generated later
[rosbuild] Couldn't find source file /home/turtlebot/rgbdslam_freiburg/rgbdslam/build/src/moc_ros_service_ui.cxx; assuming that it is in /home/turtlebot/rgbdslam_freiburg/rgbdslam and will be generated later
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/74899/rosmake-rgbdslam_freiburg-error-in-groovy/) by [FfoNy](https://answers.ros.org/users/4511/ffony/) on ROS Answers with karma: 62 on 2013-08-26

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It is a known problem in groovy, that rgbdslam doesn't find libg2o. A hackish solution that worked for one person and didn't work for a second one is this:

delete the following line in rgbdslam/CMakeLists.txt

```
find_package(libg2o REQUIRED)
```

replace the following line

```
SET(G2O_LIBS ${libg2o_LIBRARIES} cholmod cxsparse)
```

by

```
SET(G2O_LIBS cholmod cxsparse -lg2o_cli -lg2o_core
-lg2o_csparse_extension -lg2o_ext_freeglut_minimal -lg2o_incremental
-lg2o_interactive -lg2o_interface -lg2o_opengl_helper -lg2o_parser
-lg2o_simulator -lg2o_solver_cholmod -lg2o_solver_csparse
-lg2o_solver_dense -lg2o_solver_pcg -lg2o_solver_slam2d_linear
-lg2o_solver_structure_only -lg2o_stuff -lg2o_types_data -lg2o_types_icp
-lg2o_types_sba -lg2o_types_sclam2d -lg2o_types_sim3 -lg2o_types_slam2d
-lg2o_types_slam3d)
```

I am not using groovy but I will happily patch rgbdslam if someone has a reliable solution to this.

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2013-08-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [FfoNy](https://answers.ros.org/users/4511/ffony/) on 2013-08-28**:
Thanks  for your answer. This is right.

**Comment by [RodBelaFarin](https://answers.ros.org/users/3527/rodbelafarin/) on 2013-12-02**:
I am the person that it worked for, so it's true working :D

**Comment by [KaiserUDM](https://answers.ros.org/users/9476/kaiserudm/) on 2013-12-03**:
I just wanted to add that I'm using ROS Electric and this fix worked for me. I followed this comment and it complied on the very next try.

**Comment by [thchung](https://answers.ros.org/users/1467/thchung/) on 2013-12-07**:
This worked for me on Ubuntu 12.04.3 + ROS Groovy.  Thanks!

**Comment by [hgtc-dp](https://answers.ros.org/users/15556/hgtc-dp/) on 2014-05-19**:
this worked on ubuntu 12.04+ ROS groovy thanks